# cascading behavior lost when using specific classes in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails3

The basic associated flights are saved correctly in cascading way when using eg. `Set` for the association, but not when having a derived class for it:

```
class Airport {
    String name
```

version #1: `Set flights`

version #2: `DerivedSet flights`

```
    static hasMany = [flights: Flight]
}

class Flight {
    String number
    static belongsTo = [airport: Airport]
}

new Airport(name: "Gatwick")
        .addToFlights(new Flight(number: "BA3430"))
        .addToFlights(new Flight(number: "EZ0938"))
        .save(flush: true)
```

**version #1** cascading save is working fine.
**version #2** cascading is not working (`DerivedSet` is `class DerivedSet extends Set {...}`)

Probably during domain class transformation derived classes are not considered but not sure how to improve the framework to this direction.
Thanks in case anyone can help...

Comment: Possibly withTransaction required. You adding it in domain class ? Add stuff in service which is transactional or in bootstrap where `withTransaction` is possibly still required. As a test .save (flush:true)

Comment: I used it in a method in a controller which is defined to be transactional. Also flush is set to true. So it seems not this is the problem but thanks